# Is it possible to define hash route in next.js?

Tags: javascript, react-router, modal-dialog, next.js

I had already made a modal component with `<HashRouter>` in `react-router` that became active and inactive with hash url i.e modals is inactive when url is `/route` and `modal1` is active when url is `/route#modal1`.
There is any ways to define hash routes in next.js?

Comment: what were your attempts? are you using next.js with custom server?

Comment: I didn't find anything in next.js document to define hash routes. Yes, I'm using next.js with custom server.

Comment: and with which server? express?

Comment: My server is express.

Comment: You could probably use React Router with hash-based routing on a single Next.js page. I'm going to do this for a new SaaS product that shouldn't server-side render pages (except for a loading state) that don't need SEO because they're accessible only via login. I don't see this clashing with the Next.js router as React Router would unmount and deactivate when navigating to another Next.js page.

Answer (score 16):

The part of the url starting with the hash symbol (that identifies an html entity) is never sent to the server, so you cant match the url serverside (if the browser loads `/route#modal1` the server will load `/route`) what you can do is :

**Option 1** Handle the modal rendering client side, using `next/router`  in your component with something like this :
(im assuming you are using class components)

```
  import Router from 'next/router'

  ....

  componentDidMount(){
    let id = Router.asPath.match(/#([a-z0-9]+)/gi )
    if(id){
      // i will show the modal
    }else{
      // something else
    }
  }
```

**Option 2** Pass the id to the url without `#`.
In your `server.js` add a route similar to this :

```
  server.get('/route/:id?', (req, res) => {
    let {id} =  req.params 
    return app.render(req, res, '/mypage', { id})
  })
```

And then grab the id, ex. in `getInitialProps`

```
  static async getInitialProps (context) {
    let ctx  = context.query;
    return ctx
  }
```

And handle the modal

```
  componentDidMount(){
    let {id} =  this.props    
    if(id){
      // i will show the modal
    }else{
      // something else
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hey @Nico, Can you post another answer here for NextJs13+ (appRouter) please?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `next/router` to accomplish that.

In our case we use hash routing on a specific page to render different components depending on the hash url, so the user can go back and forth using regular web navigations buttons

```js
// page.js

export default function MyPage() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const hash = router.asPath.split('#')[1] || '';
  const showModal = hash === 'modal1' ? true : false;
  const openModal = () => {
    router.push({ hash: 'modal1' });
  }  
  return (
    <>
      <h1>MyPage</h1>
      <Button onClick={openModal}>Open Modal </Button>
      {showModal && <ModalOne />}
    </>
  )
}
```

```js
// ModalOne.js

export default function ModelOne {
  const router = useRouter();
  const closeModal = () => {
    router.push({ hash: '' });
  }
  return (
    <>
        <h1>Hello Modal</h1>
        <Button onClick={closeModal}>Close Modal </Button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Every time the router hash changes a re render is triggered, opening the modal in a similar way to what you would expect on a SPA

This also has the added benefit of closing the modal when pressing back on a mobile device, as it was in our use case expectations.

Note: I'm using nextjs version 12.1.0

Answer (score 3):

You can add a hash using the next/router.

Some pages I change the component that renders based on a state string, so to make sure I know which route I'm on (and keep the back button working) I add a state string `stage` as a hash to the URL when it detects a change.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  router.push(`/booking#${stage}`)
}, [stage])
```

This will only work client side though.

Comment: this solution fails when using router.push by passing in { pathname: '...url', query: '...query' }